# Laravel string data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

I have pivot table `post_tags` which will store id of post and id of tag

`PS:` all my tables using `uuid`.

Now when I try to add/change my post tags in update function it returns this error:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'tag_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `post_tags` (`id`, `post_id`, `tag_id`) values (d0fb529e-38ac-4197-9455-e41898de9d05, c4a41a90-1274-4830-8974-71d6b5834216, bd89cf45-bb85-4e4b-93f8-342e86dbaa31,9adc54df-e778-432d-be25-282169a7c5af))"
```

#### Code

```
//.....
$post->save();
$tags_id = (array) $request->input('tags');
foreach( $tags_id as $tag_id ) {
  $tag_data_to_sync[ $tag_id ] = [ 'id' => \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString() ];
}
$post->tags()->sync( $tag_data_to_sync );
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Please include your migration file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

My tags ids came like `"86198680-1f0b-4544-851a-4c39e4f7c3ec,2bbe9776-7413-43fa-9cae-3378f39f3c2d"` and I had to explode my tags data in order to loop them

```
$tags_id = explode(',', $request->input('tags'));
```

Now works just fine.

Comment: Also as an addition ensure to trim or remove all white space as this can throw the same error. 
`explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $request->categories))`